# onReceive in BroadcastReceiver doesn't get called sometimes

Tags: android

I registered receiver in onCreate, but onReceive sometimes get called, sometimes not.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v("receiver","get called");

    }
}
```

Here is how I register receiver in onCreate

```
PROCESS_RESPONSE = getBaseContext().getResources().getString(R.string.serviceResponse);
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROCESS_RESPONSE);
filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
receiver = new MyReceiver();
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Here is how I send broadcast:

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
PROCESS_RESPONSE=getBaseContext().getResources().getString(R.string.serviceResponse);
broadcastIntent.setAction(PROCESS_RESPONSE);
broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT); 
sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

Comment: Link code for how the receiver is broadcasted to (how do you send the signal to the receiver?)

Comment: How do you register your receiver

Comment: Find the reason, it is because the data I am send make the broadcast failed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
broadcastIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
```

The reason it sometimes works and doesn't work is

> because Android 3.0 introduced a launch control security measure that prevents components of stopped applications from being launched via an intent. An application is considered to be in a stopped state if the application has either just been installed and not previously launched, or been manually stopped by the user using the application manager on the device. To get around this, however, a flag can be added to the intent before it is sent to indicate that the intent is to be allowed to start a component of a stopped application.

[Quote source](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Broadcast_Intents_and_Broadcast_Receivers)

So when you try a fresh install (launching from IDE) the application is considered in the stop state for a while, then later is not. So it sometimes doesn't work when you try to broadcast. Let me know if this works, and of course ensure you have registered the BroadcastReciever (I'm sure you have if it works, at least some of the time).

Comment: Added the flags and tried a fresh install, but onReceive is still not getting called sometimes.